# Shell Scripting error

Tags: unix, shell, scripting

I'm very new to shell scripting and i've been struggling with the following shell script. I'm posting the script and the commands i used below for your consideration please help me with the mistake i made.

```
#
#
#

DBG=0
RLS=0
ALL=0
CLN=0

print_help_uu()
{
        echo "Usage: $0 -D -R -A -C "; 
        echo "Where -C clean the debug project builds";
        echo "      -D to build in DEBUG config";
        echo "      -R to build in RELEASE config";
        echo "      -A to build in both configs";
        return
}

#
# Main procedure start here
#
# Check for sufficent args
#

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
        print_help_uu
        exit 1
fi    

#
# Function to clean the project
#
clean()
{
        if ["$DBG"="1"]; then
            echo "Cleaning debug"

            if ["$RLS"="1"]; then
                echo "cleaning release + debug"
            else
                echo "This is bad"
            fi
        fi

        if ["$RLS"="1"]; then 
            echo "Cleaning release "
        fi
        return
}


while getopts "DRAC" opt
do
        case "$opt" in
                D) DBG=1;;
                R) RLS=1;;
                A) DBG=1;RLS=1;;
                C) CLN=1;;
                \?) print_help_uu; exit 1;; 
        esac
        clean
done
```

I'm posting the commands i used to run it and the errors i got when using those commands.

```
----------
./BuildProject.sh -D
./BuildProject.sh: line 36: [1=1]: command not found
./BuildProject.sh: line 46: [0=1]: command not found

-----------
sh BuildProject.sh -D
BuildProject.sh: 63: [1=1]: not found
BuildProject.sh: 63: [0=1]: not found

-----------
sh ./BuildProject.sh -D
./BuildProject.sh: 63: [1=1]: not found
./BuildProject.sh: 63: [0=1]: not found
```

I tried to solve it in soo many ways and googled a lot before posting here. But all my trials went in vain. Please tell me where i'm doing the mistake since i'm new to shell scripting.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[` is a command, but you are trying to invoke the command `[1=1]`. Add some whitespace:

```
if [ "$DBG" = "1" ]; then
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to change `["$DBG"="1"]` (and similar if statements) into this: `[ "$DBG" = "1" ]`
i.e. add some space.

Answer (score 2):

i think it's a "SPACE" problem : try

```
if [ "$DBG" = "1" ]; then
```

instead of

```
if ["$DBG"="1"]; then
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a space issue indeed.

```
VAR=VALUE
```

is only for variable declaration in shell, while

```
VAR = VALUE
```

is only for variable testing. It's tricky, you just have to get used to it.

Comment: Got the Trick Raphink. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It Worked after adding some extra spaces into it. Thank you all. Is it a Scripting rule to put those spaces in between the variables?? I think i ignored that rule. Thanks for your time.

Comment: It's a syntax rule in Bash. It is not needed for all scripting/programming languages, but for some it does and Bash is one such language.

Comment: Thank you Emil for enlightening me.